# Как в PhpStorm сохранить размер экрана?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

При каждой новой перезагрузке PhpStorm у меня слетают те настройки размера рабочей области (размеры экрана), которые я задавал с помощью Ctrl+скролл мыши.

Как исправить, и почему возникает? Версия 2016.3.2

Comment: Завести тикет в багтрекере, не? https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI

Comment: Можно подробнее? Я только начал обучатся данной IDE

Comment: @BlackStar1991 у компании JetBrains, производящей в том числе PhpStorm, есть специальный сайт, где вы можете сообщить об ошибке или любом другом затруднении. Ссылка выше. Наверное там сначала нужно завести учётную запись.